# Unable to extract value by using css selector

Tags: css, python-2.7, scrapy

I have below html response from some web api. I have used scrapy a python framework to parse the web page but I am unable to extract some of the text

```
<div class="title-container">
    <div class="title">
        <span class="number">1</span>
        <!--comment-->
        "Title"
        <!--comment-->
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract the word "Title".
I have used response.css('div.title-container div.title::text').extract_first()
but I am getting response as "1".

I appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: Not familiar with scrapy, but I'm willing to hazard a guess that your `::text` is what's throwing you off here - to me that reads as "get the text node within this element".

Comment: Thanks Scoots for your attention.. forget about scrapy then.. I just need to write css selector to extract "Title"

Comment: Text cannot be **selected** by CSS...only styled.